# Django admin search icon become SO BIG after install django cms on top of django

Tags: django, django-cms

I have install django and create django project. everything was working fine untill i install django-cms than my django project and django cms project is getting weird for exam the search icons become so big.

I think it is conflict between django cms and django css style or something. Can anyone recommend me any solution to this? thank you

[image]

Comment: That isn't loading `djangocms_admin_style` properly. It needs to be in your `INSTALLED_APPS` before `django.contrib.admin`

Comment: I have djangocms_admin_style just before django.contrib.admin with django 1.11.x and django-cms 3.6.0 and djangocms_admin_style 1.2.9 and I have the same huge search icon.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem above. I was missusing https://github.com/sonus21/CollectTemplate, I collected admin templates, but I didn't collected djangocms_admin_style templates so regular admin templates where those that were discovered first as they were in my project.